# I want to switch button off when the timer is done

Tags: android

OnCheckChanged
i want to check if the isChecked 
the timer start and when its done i want to switch it to off and stop the button

```
    if(isChecked){

                              //on
                        timer.start();

                        Client myClient= new Client(serverIP,serverPort,t1,"h");
                        myClient.execute();
                        String data=t1.getText().toString();

                  Toast.makeText(getContext(),data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        buttonView.setText("On irrigation");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Irrigation On" + getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if(time==0)
                        {
                            buttonView.setChecked(false);
                             myClient= new Client(serverIP,serverPort,t1,"g");

                            myClient.execute();
                         data=t1.getText().toString();

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Countdown` timer:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

              // Here whatever you want to process in the mean time.
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);  

         }

         public void onFinish() {

            // Here you can set your button to off state.

         }
      }.start();
```